# Display Camera Roll like in the Twitter App?

Tags: ios, iphone, twitter, camera, photo

How would you display a users photos like in the twitter application where the photostream is right under the keyboard like this:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I don't know how Twitter actually implemented (duh), however you could achieve this using a container. Simply create the `UIImagePicker` into memory and instead of using `presentViewController...`, just add it as a child view controller. I have not tested this approach so I'm making this a comment until someone does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my own question by using the component `RRMessageController`  https://github.com/remirobert/RRMessageController

Answer (score 1):

[image: Add the AssetsLibrary framework]

Then write some code similar to:

```
@interface ImageCell : UICollectionViewCell

@property (strong) UIImageView *imageView;

@end

@implementation ImageCell

- (instancetype)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];

    self.imageView = [UIImageView new];

    [self addSubview:self.imageView];

    return self;
}

- (void)layoutSubviews
{
    [super layoutSubviews];

    self.imageView.frame = self.bounds;
}

@end
```

Then:

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import <AssetsLibrary/AssetsLibrary.h>

@interface ViewController ()

@property (strong) NSMutableArray *thumbnails;
@property (strong) UICollectionView *collectionView;

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.collectionView = [[UICollectionView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectInset(self.view.bounds, 20, 20)
                                             collectionViewLayout:[UICollectionViewFlowLayout new]];

    self.collectionView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

    [self.collectionView registerClass:[ImageCell class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"Cell"];

    self.collectionView.dataSource = self;
    self.collectionView.delegate = self;

    [self.view addSubview:self.collectionView];

    ALAssetsLibrary *library = [ALAssetsLibrary new];

    self.thumbnails = [NSMutableArray new];

    __weak ViewController *weakSelf = self;

    [library enumerateGroupsWithTypes:ALAssetsGroupAll usingBlock:^(ALAssetsGroup *group, BOOL *stop) {

        [group enumerateAssetsUsingBlock:^(ALAsset *result, NSUInteger index, BOOL *stop) {

            ViewController *strongSelf = weakSelf;

            if(!result.thumbnail)
                return;

            [strongSelf.thumbnails addObject:[UIImage imageWithCGImage:result.thumbnail]];

            [strongSelf updateUI];
        }];

    } failureBlock:^(NSError *error){}];
}

- (void)updateUI
{
    [self.collectionView reloadData];
}

- (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return self.thumbnails.count;
}

- (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout *)collectionViewLayout sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UIImage *image = self.thumbnails[indexPath.row];

    return image.size;
}

- (UICollectionViewCell*)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    ImageCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    cell.imageView.image = self.thumbnails[indexPath.row];

    return cell;
}

@end
```

This code needs to be optimized from here depending on the requirements of the app. It also needs to customize the collection view frame and layout to match UI requirements.

[image: Screenshot of Result]

Comment: What do you mean by updating the UI to show `self.thumbnails`, could you show me a general example.

Comment: There's a lot of code involved in doing it correctly, but sure.

Answer (score 0):

```
UIImagePickerController *imagePickerController = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
imagePickerController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationCurrentContext;
imagePickerController.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
[self presentViewController:imagePickerController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Comment: that simply displays it when tapping a button, i wanted it to be displayed by default in the View Controller.

Answer (score 0):

There's a [class](https://github.com/wenzhaot/InstagramPhotoPicker) that mimics that exact same behaviour:

[image]

You can download it from here: [Link](https://github.com/wenzhaot/InstagramPhotoPicker)